# Missing color support (for exa) in eshell

Tags: eshell, colors

I just started using eshell. But the color support for some commands seems to be missing. For example I like to use the command `exa`, because of its nice colors. But in eshell it is all black.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `exa` in eshell you can just use the following alias. It is preserved over a restart of Emacs.

```
alias exa *exa --color=always
```

The general problem to teach other programs about the color capabilities of the comint  of Emacs is [described on Rededit](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/8ptscw/better_term_setting_for_shelleshell/e0eg2mt/).

This approach helps for an example colorizing `git` output under Eshell.

Lax Citation:

Create a file `~/.terminfo/dumb-emacs-ansi.ti` with the following content:

```terminfo
dumb-emacs-ansi|Emacs dumb terminal with ANSI color codes,
    am,
    colors#8, it#8, ncv#13, pairs#64,
    bold=\E[1m, cud1=^J, ht=^I, ind=^J, op=\E[39;49m,
    ritm=\E[23m, rmul=\E[24m, setab=\E[4%p1%dm,
    setaf=\E[3%p1%dm, sgr0=\E[m, sitm=\E[3m, smul=\E[4m,
```

Runs `tic` on that file.
Set the environment variable `TERM` in Eshell to `dumb-emacs-ansi`.

The following Elisp code does that for you:

```el
(setq comint-terminfo-terminal "dumb-emacs-ansi")

(let* ((terminfo-file (format "~/.terminfo/%s.ti" comint-terminfo-terminal))
       (default-directory (file-name-directory terminfo-file)))
  (unless (file-exists-p terminfo-file)
    (make-directory default-directory t)
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert "dumb-emacs-ansi|Emacs dumb terminal with ANSI color codes,
    am,
    colors#8, it#8, ncv#13, pairs#64,
    bold=\\E[1m, cud1=^J, ht=^I, ind=^J, op=\\E[39;49m,
    ritm=\\E[23m, rmul=\\E[24m, setab=\\E[4%p1%dm,
    setaf=\\E[3%p1%dm, sgr0=\\E[m, sitm=\\E[3m, smul=\\E[4m,")
      (write-file terminfo-file)))
  (unless (file-exists-p (concat default-directory "d/" comint-terminfo-terminal))
    (start-process "*tic process*" "*Messages*" "tic" (expand-file-name terminfo-file))))

(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook '(lambda ()
                   (setenv "TERM" comint-terminfo-terminal)))
```